# Displayed Icon in Notification Drawer

Tags: java, android, notifications, icons, builder

I'd like to ask if it's possible to use the LargeIcon as the displayed icon in the notification drawer when it's not scrolled down.

Explicit:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder warningBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
Bitmap appWarningIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
    R.drawable.alert_warnings_yellow);
warningBuilder.setLargeIcon(appWarningIcon); // I want this Icon to be displayed in the disabled notification drawer
warningBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher); //but currently this one is displayed
warningBuilder.setContentTitle("Warning: ");
warningBuilder.setContentText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.alert_warning_message)));
warningBuilder.setLights(Color.YELLOW, 500, 500);
warningBuilder.setVibrate(new long[] {
    100, 250, 100, 250, 100, 250
});
warningBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
    .bigText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.alert_warning_message))));
NotificationManager warningNotificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
warningNotificationManager.notify(4, warningBuilder.build());
```

I know that this setup is the default option from the NotificationBuilder but is there a way to avoid this behaviour?
If my question isn't explicit enough please don't hestitate in asking detailed questions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there's no way to use a Bitmap for the small icon but you could just do a:

```
warningBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.alert_warnings_yellow);
```

If you want to use a different small icon in the expanded layout than in the ticker style notification (when the notification drawer is closed) then you'd need to use a custom layout for the notification:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CustomNotification

There are plenty of examples on how to create your own notification layout on SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+custom+notification+layout

Comment: First thank you for taking the time and looking into my post. But the problem is that there would be 2 times the same icon. My goal would be to display the "warningIcon" in the "disabled" notification drawer. And when I scroll down the drawer I would see the "warningIcon" on the left side of the notification and the "ic_launcher icon" on the right side - of course as a small bitmap. Because the builder uses  the smallIcon for the disabled drawer by default